# Android Studio, Java, TextView not reflecting what I coded

Tags: java, android-studio

Good evening community,

I am currently trying to make a layout and my code dosen't reflect what it should be.

Here is what it's suppose to look like:

[image]

Basically the text blend into the tealish bar

and this is what I have:

[image]

What to do?

Comment: couldn't understand your question?what's your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your Image is clear but your question is not, in the TextView you have to place the text what ever you want Hardcoded or not.

android:text="Your text here"

but if you want your TextView to show different results, you have to place an ID of TextView and initialize it in your Java code